# How to run reactNativeFragment inside existing application

Tags: javascript, java, android, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to integrate react native into existing Android application. Most of the code, js will be running 'headless'(no ui, only logic), and communicate with android UI.
Now I'm at a point when I want to open small JS fragment inside the android application, purely for debug tools. I followed the official documentation of how to migrate react native into existing app, but my issue is that attempting to open reactNativeFragment results in opening another JS thread(can see another thread in chrome tools).

This is the place where I start my react native process (it only loads js, not the UI).

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(getApplication()).getPackages();
        packages.add(new MyAppPackage());
        
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setCurrentActivity(this)
                .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
                .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .addPackages(packages)
                .setDefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler(this)
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();

        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, "hermesdm2", null);
```

And here, I have a button that should open JS UI window that I can use for debug purposes(easier to debug from js):

```
        mButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
        View frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.reactNativeFragment);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment reactNativeFragment = new ReactFragment.Builder()
                        .setComponentName("hermesdm2")
                        .setFabricEnabled(false)
                        .build();
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .add(R.id.reactNativeFragment, reactNativeFragment)
                        .commit();
                frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
```

But, as I said, this opens another JS process instead of reusing existing one, which I dont want to. How would I do that?

I tried to play around with component names, I tried to run the existing reactRootView inside the fragment too(that actually should be possible but I didnt success so far.